# How to share a file path such that the receiver can open his local file from my link?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, file-sharing

We have a typical office setup and we use tortoise client for SVN. Now whenever I update any file in my local repository and want to share it's path with other developers, I can only share the relative or absolute path from my system. By receiving such link the user will have to manually go to the parent folder of my relative path and then reach the specified file.
Is there a way such that I can specify links to any file in my SVN and the receivers upon getting those links are able to open the file directly just by clicking the link?

Comment: Why aren't you using a central SVN server and having each developer maitnain a working copy on their desktop?

Comment: Yes it is the way I am using. But when I have to notify about any change that I have done, I want to send a working link.

Comment: There's no need to "notify" if everyone is keeping their WCs up to date. Run `svn update`, get the file in its new location.

Comment: @alroc A notification after any update is a nice way in software industry to update others about the changes that you are making. A full like helps others to know exactly which file I am talking about and if the link can open the file then its like magic.

Answer (score 0):

This would only be possible if you knew where the file is located on your peer's machine.

Then, you could specify an absolute path that your peer could open.

Otherwise, there's no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use VisualSVN Server's web interface to get shareable links. For example, navigate to the demo server at [https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#documents/view/head/TypeScript Language Specification.docx](https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#documents/view/head/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.docx) and click the **Copy repository URL** button on the right side of the navbar. You can also copy the URL from your web browser's address bar.

And this link leads to a particular line of a file at revision 1833062: https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#asf/view/r1873062/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_diff/diff.c?line=50.